# woking sorting and editing div at a time issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem in my script is that when I am using  sortable for div the input textbox is not editable.

I have drag and drop functionality in my code after drop,the div must be sortable and input must be editable for further use.
I want both the functionality to run at a time
I use following methds but it is not working

Here is my code

```
$(".workArea").sortable();
$('.workArea').sortable({handle: 'div'}).disableSelection();
$(".workArea").sortable("option", "appendTo", 'body' );
$(".workArea").sortable("option", "cancel", ':input');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've seen others solve this by setting the sortable with `delay` or `distance` options: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Sortable#option-delay  I am not submitting this as an answer, though, because I haven't tried it myself.  If it works, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.workArea').sortable({handle: 'div'});
$('.workArea div').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.workArea').sortable()

TRy above code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $(".workArea").sortable("option", "cancel", ':input','.contenteditable');
```

or

```
  $(".workArea").sortable({cancel: ':input,button,.contenteditable'});
```

Both works like a charm!

Comment: @ sandip : Hey it is working only one at a time either it is editable or sortable i want both at a time